# how do to update and remove and replace the record of the user?

Tags: c

[EDIT]

to reserve a seat, I asked for information about the user and requested a seat that will be marked by 'x'

```
void reserve(){
    passenger addpassenger;
    FILE *fp, *fp1;

    fp=fopen("passenger.txt", "a+");
    fp1=fopen("passenger1.txt", "a+");

    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t PLEASE ENTER YOUR DETAILS BELOW:");
    printf("\n\t\t\t---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\n\t\t\tEnter your name:");
    scanf(" %s",addpassenger.name);

    printf("\t\t\tEnter your age: ");
    scanf(" %d", &addpassenger.age);

    printf("\t\t\tEnter your city: ");
    scanf(" %s", addpassenger.city);
    printf("\n");

    displayseat();

     printf("\nEnter your seat number: (EX: 1A)");
        scanf(" %d%c",&addpassenger.seatrow, &addpassenger.seatcol);

        if (addpassenger.seatrow > 0 && addpassenger.seatrow < ROWS &&
            addpassenger.seatcol >= 'A' && addpassenger.seatcol <= 'A' + COLS){


                if (seat[addpassenger.seatrow - 1][addpassenger.seatcol - 'A'] != 'X'){
                    // Seat is available, reserve it and break the loop.
                    seat[addpassenger.seatrow - 1][addpassenger.seatcol - 'A'] = 'X';
                    printf("Congratulations. Your seat number is %d%c\n",addpassenger.seatrow,addpassenger.seatcol);
                }
                else{

                    printf("Seat is already taken. Choose another seat? (Y/N)\n.");
                    scanf(" %c", &answer);
                if (answer != 'Y'){
                    printf("Your data will be not saved and will be returned to main menu.\n");
                }
        }
        
    }
    else{
            printf("Invalid seat row/col,\n");
}
    fwrite(&addpassenger, PASSENGERSIZE, 1, fp1);
    fprintf(fp, " \n%d\t\t%s\t%d\t%s\t%d%c", addpassenger.name, addpassenger.age,addpassenger.city, addpassenger.seatrow,addpassenger.seatcol);
    

fclose(fp);
fclose(fp1);
}
```

to update the user seat, my problem is how can I display the mark 'x' like in the reserve function. where I display the 'x' mark on the input of the user herein update

````
void update(){
    passenger record;

    FILE *fp, *fp1, *fp2;

    char passengername[MAXNAME];
    int found=0;

    fp=fopen("passenger.txt", "r");
    fp1=fopen("passenger1.txt", "r");
    fp2=fopen("temp.txt","w");

    printf("\n\t\t\tEnter your name to update your seat: ");
    scanf(" %s", passengername);

    while( fread(&record, PASSENGERSIZE, 1, fp1 ) ) 
    {
        if ( strcmp( record.name, passengername ) == 0 ) 
        {
            found=1;
            displayseat();

            printf( "\n\t\t\tUpdate your seat number: (EX: 1A)" );
            scanf( " %d%c", &record.seatrow, &record.seatcol );

            

        }fwrite(&record, PASSENGERSIZE, 1, fp2);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

    if(found){
       fp=fopen("passenger.txt", "w");
       fp1=fopen("passenger1.txt", "w");
       fp2=fopen("temp.txt","r");

       while(fread(&record, PASSENGERSIZE, 1,fp2)){
        fwrite(&record, PASSENGERSIZE, 1,fp1);
        fprintf(fp, " \n%d\t\t%s\t%d\t%s\t%d%c", record.name, record.age,record.city, record.seatrow,record.seatcol);
       }
       fclose(fp);
       fclose(fp1);
       fclose(fp2);
    }
    else{
        printf("\nRecord not found\n");
    }
}```

working on the same seat reservation program, I am troubled with how can I change user input in my table. At first, I requested them to input their desired seat number in the ```create(); ``` function. This mark 'X' on the table after they entered their seat.
````

void create(){
struct passenger addpassenger;

```
 printf("\nEnter your seat number: (EX: 1A)");
    scanf(" %d%c",&addpassenger.seatrow, &addpassenger.seatcol);


    if (addpassenger.seatrow > 0 && addpassenger.seatrow < ROWS &&
        addpassenger.seatcol >= 'A' && addpassenger.seatcol <= 'A' + COLS){
            ++countpassenger;


            if (seat[addpassenger.seatrow - 1][addpassenger.seatcol - 'A'] != 'X'){
                // Seat is available, reserve it and break the loop.
                seat[addpassenger.seatrow - 1][addpassenger.seatcol - 'A'] = 'X';
                printf("Congratulations. Your seat number is %d%c\n",addpassenger.seatrow,addpassenger.seatcol);
            }
            else{
                // Seat is already taken.
                printf("Seat is already taken. Choose another seat? (Y/N)\n.");
                scanf(" %c", &answer);
            if (answer != 'Y'){
                printf("Your data will be not saved and will be returned to main menu.\n");
            }
    }
    
}
else{
   
        printf("Invalid seat row/col,\n");
```

}
}

```
Now I want to update the user's seat. It did change the seat they entered on display but the mark on the table didn't change. And this is the part where I asked the user to update their record.
```

void update(){
struct passenger record;

```
        printf( "\n\t\t\tUpdate your seat number: (EX: 1A)" );
        scanf( " %d%c", &record.seatrow, &record.seatcol );
```

}

```
my table array is
```

char seat[MIN][MAX]

````
and I call it in the table as ```seat[0][0],seat[0][1]....```

I am just wondering how can I change the mark on the table. Which part should I change and work on? and do I need to add the same if else formula from the function ```create``` on the ```update``` function that I am working on?
````

Comment: not sure what you're asking, but what if the user would like to choose another seat? If they enter `Y`, nothing happens. You need to loop back around and prompt them to enter another seat.

Comment: You also should only `++countpassenger` when a new seat is assigned. What if I enter the same seat 500 times? That should still only count towards one passenger on the plane.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the steps involved for updating a seat are 1) user enters their original seat. Is this seat valid _and_ already assigned? 2) user enters their new seat selection. Is this new seat valid _and_ empty? 3) If true for both, clear the first seat, assign the second seat. There's some overlap with these steps and assigning a new seat as you're already doing, you should try to write functions with common reusable code that can be used in both operations.

Comment: @yano, I see, but in updating the user seat I plan to enter their name to access their record which where they entered their original seat, and then I'll ask them to enter a new seat again to replace their original seat. Now my program already updated its seat, but my problem is how can I display them on the table because it displays the original seat which they entered before.

Comment: sounds like something is wrong in the `update` function if the seat is in fact not getting updated. You'll need to post the code to that function if you want some help.

Comment: There is no need for a space before `scanf(" %s" ...` or `" %d"`. In fact the only conversion specifiers that do NOT discard leading whitespace are `"%c"`, `"%[...]"` and `"%n"` -- all others ignore leading whitespace on their own.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks again, they've been reminding me of that but I kept forgetting it. I'll work on it again, thank you

Comment: @yano I have already posted the code, the seat is getting updated, its just that the formula for it to mark 'x' on the new seat entered is my problem because when I tried the same if/else-if formula, the previous seat is still marked. I want to mark the updated seat as X, removing the previous seat to be marked

Comment: @gwen, Yano was asking your to please provide [A Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: looks like you're nearly there with the `update` function. You should write 2 functions: `bool IsSeatTaken(int row, int col)` and `bool AssignSeat(passenger* p, int row, int col);` `IsSeatTaken` returns true if the seat is already assigned, and `AssignSeat` returns true (and assigns the seat to `p`) if the seat could be assigned. Both these functions can be used in initial assignment and update operations.